# Difference between 悠閒 and 優閒

Tags: meaning

Are these adjectives or nouns? They both look to me to mean relaxing/to relax, so what's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 悠閒 (leisurely) and 休閒 (leisure)? 優閒 is not a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

悠閒 - **悠然**閒暇

優閒 - **優渥**閒暇

Both mean a person in a state of "relaxed without worry". The difference is the former means "without worry spiritually", and the latter means "live well without worry about material/monetary needs.